# ¿Por qué una "pájara" es un bajón físico en ciclismo?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, deportes

[Pájara](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RTabDql) es

> 8. f. En ciclismo, bajón físico súbito que impide al corredor mantener el ritmo de la carrera.

¿Cómo adquirió ese significado? ¿Es un uso exclusivo del ciclismo?

Answer (score 3):

No es un uso exclusivo del ciclismo. Se utiliza en muchos ámbitos, incluyendo varios no relacionados con el deporte.

A falta de una fuente fiable, por experiencia propia te puedo decir que una "pájara" se asimila mucho a los síntomas de agotamiento y deshidratacion en las aves, que caen al suelo y aletean sin equilibrio.

Answer (score 3):

[Esta entrada de wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A1jara_(deporte)) define la pájara como

> una situación en que el rendimiento físico se deteriora bruscamente a causa del agotamiento de las reservas de glucógeno del hígado y los músculos.

El efecto de la pájara es un "querer y no poder". Intentas hacer algo y el cuerpo no responde. Debido al agotamiento físico, quien sufre una *pajara* demuestra como torpeza.

Lo interesante de la entrada de la wikipedia viene en la siguiente sección (otros nombres), cuando dice:

> A partir de la expresión inglesa hitting the wall también se usan los términos chocar contra el muro o golpear el muro. Dicha expresión se comenzó a utilizar a mediados del siglo XX en el ámbito del ciclismo

Y aunque no lo dice expresamente, el "golpear el muro" me recuerda a lo que hacen las aves atrapadas en una habitación, intentado salir por una ventana cerrada y dándose golpe tras golpe. Tras cada golpe por supuesto quedan más fatigadas y atontadas, y de ahí esa "torpeza".

Así que entiendo que el uso de "pájara" en el ámbito deportivo viene de un uso metafórico de la torpeza de las aves al realizar ciertas actividades.

Answer (score 0):

Según dicen, podría tener relación con el municipio de Pájara, en Fuerteventura, donde los accesos curvos y empinados a través de la cordillera de la isla, provocaban este tipo de agotamiento físico en las personas que intentaban acceder al pueblo.