# Pájara mental -adopted use or generally accepted

Tags: uso-de-palabras

I learnt a new word from [an article](https://elpais.com/espana/2023-11-02/los-jovenes-que-quieren-que-lo-rural-mole-de-nuevo.html) I received in a newsletter from El País. It is "pájara" or in this case "pájara mental".

I see from the RAE that it means:

> En ciclismo, bajón físico súbito que impide al corredor mantener el
> ritmo de la carrera.
>
> [EN] A physical collapse while cycling which impedes the cyclist from keeping the same rhythm (or probably stops him entirely).

Note: I see this word has been asked about on this site previously but my question is slightly different.

Anyway, my questions are:

1. Can it be used for other sports, physical activity in general? Examples: hillwalking or exhaustion from swimming or even after doing a lot of household chores. I feel the last one is a bit of a push.

Also, from the article, it seems it can be transferred to mental exhaustion also.

2. Is this generally accepted or is the writer being playful? I can't find other examples online. Can I use it liberally and be understood?

Comment: Point 1 was included in the [other question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19006/por-qu%c3%a9-una-p%c3%a1jara-es-un-baj%c3%b3n-f%c3%adsico-en-ciclismo?rq=1) that you mentioned: "¿Es un uso exclusivo del ciclismo?"

Comment: I have no access to the full article. Can you include the part where the origin of LaPerdizRoja is explained? I'm not sure if the author is using the right term, he may mean ["paja mental"](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/paja_mental) instead.

Comment: Not used in other sports, for example, football (soccer). Just sounds like mental fatigue or loss of mental energy.

Comment: It's used in football. One example: https://as.com/futbol/2009/02/07/mas_futbol/1233991634_850215.html

Comment: In the other question is also compared to English expression ["hit the wall"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hit-the-wall). I agree with the answer there that "tener una pájara" is equivalent to that.

Comment: @RubioRic. Sorry, I don't understand .The link I clicked on above links to the whole article I read.

Comment: @Bluelion7 But you need to pay to have access to the full content. I can only read the first three lines. There is no explanation there about why is considered a pájara the creation of LaPerdizRoja.

Comment: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19006/por-qu%c3%a9-una-p%c3%a1jara-es-un-baj%c3%b3n-f%c3%adsico-en-ciclismo [RubioRic,  you need a subject in English: In the other question **it is** also compared to etc.] This is most definitely NOT hit the wall. It's to feel suddenly tired: sudden fatigue

Comment: @Lambie Thanks for the correction about the missing subject. Hit the wall: "experience a sudden loss of energy in a long race"; Pájara: "situaciones de fatiga extrema que pueden darse después de realizar un esfuerzo físico importante". Is there a relevant difference between "sudden loss of energy" and "fatigue/fatiga" in this context? I don't think so. Hope I didn't miss any word.

Comment: I think to ''hit the wall'' really is widely used especially with regard to sports and suddenly feeling exhausted and fatigued that you can't continue. It really is an apt expression in English!I feel as a native English speaker it means and translates perfectly to''pájara''